# COUNTIF inside COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, count, countif

I have a table WHERE I need to count if values are equal to "A" OR "B" OR "C" in A1:A7, but only if B1:B7 is "XYZ".

For example:

```html
A XYZ
G AAA
B ASO
C XYZ
D OOO
F ASO
A ASO
```

In this example, it should return 2 values, because the first one have A and XYZ and the 4th have C and XYZ. The 3rd and last should not be counted because it doesn't have XYZ even being A or B or C.

Basically I've thinked that a countifs could do it, with multiple countif inside it, but I can't manage it to work.
Example:

*=COUNTIFS(**COUNTIF(A1:A7; "A")+COUNTIF(A1:A7; "B")+COUNTIF(A1:A7; "C")**; B1:B7="XYZ)*

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"a",B:B,"xyz")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"b",B:B,"xyz")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"c",B:B,"xyz")
```

or

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"a";"b";"c"},B:B,"xyz"))
```

The curly brackets inside the formula define an array of criterias for the `COUNTIFS` which will be taken one after the other. The `SUM` then sums the single results. So this in principle is the same as the above.

Comment: Your second does not require array-entry.