# Q: COUNTIF only if COUNTIF

Tags: excel, count, sum, countif

I have a table where I need to count cells with the value "B" in C2:C9 but only if the corresponding row in E2:E9 isn't blank:
[image: ![table]

I got this formula from this similar question: [COUNTIF inside COUNTIFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457152/countif-inside-countifs):

=SUM(COUNTIFS(C:C, "B"),E:E,"<>"&"")

but am receiving the #VALUE! error. I'm assuming I need to add something that will match up the C and E columns with the appropriate row

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using SUM and COUNTIFS, you can get the result with COUNTIFS.

```swift
=COUNTIFS(C2:C9, "B", E2:E9, "<>")
```

Comment: "Sum and Countifs"? Do you mean Countif there?